# Angular4 CanDeactivateGuard on Child Component

Tags: angular

I want to warn the user when s/he navigates from a page and has some unsaved changes. I did it in `angular 1` with plugin `ng-unsaved changes`. But in `angular 4` , after searching all pages recommend to use `canDeactivate`. It works fine for simple form. But I have a form that has a child component. Like route navigate to a page which has Customers list and a button to add new customer. New customer is a separate component and I have added it as a child component on customer list.
Like this:

```
<!--   *** Section:CreateClient  ***  -->
<div class="row" *ngIf="pageAction=='clientDetail'">
    <div class="col-md-12">                    
        <app-client-create class="card-header-up" [clientId]="selectedClient.EntityId" (createClientResponse)='createClientCallBack($event)' [calledBy]="prmInCalledBy" [pageMode]="pageMode"></app-client-create>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if user has do some changes on this child component, `CanDeactiavte` on parent component does not fire. 
How can we access FormGroup.Dirty property of child component when user navigate 
from page.
How can we fire `CanDeactivate` on child component?
Please help with code /plunker example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use   `canActivateChild`.`canActivateChild` is called whenever changing between children of the route its defined on.

See the canAcivateChild in action at following plnkr

**[PLNKR](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/lmCeQ3)**

Comment: I am not asking about child route. Please read my question. it is about child component.